# CSS transform rotate() X axis behaves differently from Y and Z

Tags: css, rotation, transform

While working on animating a cube in CSS, I found myself that after performing a 90° rotation on Y axis, if the next rotation happened on X axis, it behaved as if it were on Z axis.
I worked on a visual representation of the space axes to be able to debug the behaviour and it looks like the X axis effectively has a dynamic orientation, meaning the rotations happen accordingly to the element own X axis, while on Y and Z axis, the rotations are always relative to the viewport.
Is this behaviour normal?
Am I missing something?

I made this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kais3rp/pen/ZEMOJQR) to debug the behaviour.
Scroll down in the viewport to perform the rotations.

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="square" class="square">
  <h4 class="v v1">1</h4>
  <h4 class="v v2">2</h4>
  <h4 class="v v3">3</h4>
  <h4 class="v v4">4</h4>
</div>
  <div id="square2" class="square">
  <h4 class="v v1">1</h4>
  <h4 class="v v2">2</h4>
  <h4 class="v v3">3</h4>
  <h4 class="v v4">4</h4>
</div>
</div>

<div id="scrollElement"></div>
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#square, #square2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position:relative;
  margin:120px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.square h4 {
  margin:0;
  color:#000;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #FFF;
  padding:3px;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.v {
  position:absolute;
}

.v1 {
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}

.v2 {
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}

.v3 {
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
}

.v4 {
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
}

#scrollElement {
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const tl = gsap.timeline();

ScrollTrigger.create({
  animation: tl,
  trigger: "#scrollElement",
  start: "top top",
  end: "100% 100%",
  scrub: 0.2
});

tl.to("#square", { rotateY: "90deg", ease: "circ.out", duration: 5 })
  .to("#square", { rotationZ: "90deg", ease: "circ.out", duration: 5 }, "<1")
  .to("#square", {
    rotateX: "90deg",
    ease: "linear",
    duration: 5
  });

////////////////////////////////////////

const el = document.querySelector("#square");
const { width, height } = el.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(width, height);
const axes = {
  x: {
    rotate: "rotateZ(90deg)",
    rotatePerp: "rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(90deg)",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    translate: `translate(0, -${height}px)`,
    translatePerp: `translate3d(0px, -${height}px, -${height}px)`,
    color: "green"
  },
  y: {
    rotate: "",
    rotatePerp: "rotateY(90deg)",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    translate: `translate(0, -${height}px)`,
    color: "yellow"
  },
  z: {
    rotate: "rotateZ(90deg) rotateX(90deg)",
    rotatePerp: "rotateX(90deg)",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    translate: `translate(0px, -${height}px)`,
    color: "blue"
  }
};
for (const key in axes) {
  const axis = axes[key];
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = key;
  div.style.transform = axis.translate + " " + axis.rotate;
  div.style.top = axis.top;
  div.style.left = axis.left;
  div.style.backgroundColor = axis.color;
  div.style.width = "5px";
  div.style.height = height*2 + "px";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.innerHTML = `<h4>${key}</h4>`;
  // Perpendicular axis
  div1.id = key + "_" + "perp";
  div1.style.transform = axis.translate + " " + axis.rotatePerp;
  div1.style.top = axis.top;
  div1.style.left = axis.left;
  div1.style.backgroundColor = axis.color;
  div1.style.width = "5px";
  div1.style.height = height*2 + "px";
  div1.style.position = "absolute";
  div1.innerHTML = `<h4>${key}</h4>`;
  el.appendChild(div);
  el.appendChild(div1);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was explained better, and then solved and answered [here](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/35895-problems-understanding-how-axis-rotation-works/). Basically:

> Yeah, it's an order of operation thing. 3D rotations can get mind-bending and gimbal lock is thorny. One of GSAP's strengths is its consistent order of operation. That's what allows you to animate each component (x, y, z, scaleX, scaleY, rotation, etc.) independently and always get clean results. In 99.9% of the cases, this is exactly what everyone wants. But if you've got one of those extremely rare edge cases where you actually want to CHANGE the order of operation, then you'd need to do that yourself in an onUpdate. You can still use GSAP to animate the values, of course, but you'd need to manage the strings.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for all three axes, not just the `x` axis and it's how it should work, per spec. Transforms applied on an element are always relative to its local coordinate system.

If you rotate an element around the `z` axis by `90deg` and then around its `y` axis, it's going to look as if the second rotation is relative to the `x` axis of the viewport. In fact, it's always relative to its own coordinate system.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 2em;
  width: 9em;
  height: 9em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
  transform: 
    perspective(25em) 
    rotatez(90deg) rotatey(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>rotatez(90deg)<br>rotatey(45deg)</div>
```

Initially, the `x` axis of an element's local coordinate system points towards 3 o'clock, its `y` axis points down, towards 6 o'clock and its `z` axis points perpendicular out of the screen towards you.

A `90deg` rotation around the `z` axis (positive rotations are clockwise) makes the `x` axis of the local coordinate system point down, towards 6 o'clock and makes the `y` axis of the local coordinate system point towards 9 o'clock. The axis we rotate around, in this case the `z` axis, remains unchanged following a rotation.

A subsequent `90deg` around the `y` axis (now pointing towards 9 o'clock, along the same line as the viewport's `x` axis) makes the `x` axis of the local coordinate system go from pointing down towards 6 o'clock to pointing perpendicular onto the screen, towards the back of it and the `z` axis go from pointing perpendicular out of the screen towards you to pointing down, towards 6 o'clock. This makes it look like the rotation happens relative to the viewport's `x` axis.

A third rotation around the `z` axis happens around the `z` axis that's now pointing down. This makes it look as if this rotation is happening around the viewport's `y` axis.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it later on that it's not just related to x axis, using GSAP it is since GSAP performs a string parsing of the transform strinjg and it always puts the rotateX property as  the first to the right. In your example the Y axis is relative to the local coordinate system, but if you later on try to perform another transform on z axis you will notice that the z axis is stuck to the viewport axis and not the local one. The relative axis is only the one on the most right of the transform string.
https://codepen.io/kais3rp/pen/JjaoywZ

Comment: Maybe it's this kind of limitation ? https://henrikingo.github.io/presentations/3D%20study/plaincss.html

Comment: I don't know what GSAP does, I've stayed away from it and all other such black boxes because I like to have control over my code, but CSS transforms are always relative to the element's local coordinate system and the coordinate system used by any subsequent transforms is the one that results from previous transforms. Updated answer with what happens when adding another rotation around the z axis after the y axis one.

Comment: You need to place perspective on the container not in the transform to understand what actually happens, they do different things, and you would realise this is not what happens "A third rotation around the z axis happens around the z axis that's now pointing down. This makes it look as if this rotation is happening around the viewport's y axis.". To do that you have to change the order of the rotate functions placing the Z axis to the most right one. I think your mental model is wrong, transform functions are compounded from right to left.

Comment: Hence if you do not work on the order of the functions to compound there are some kinds of rotations you simply can't do, it's a geometrical issue ( Gimbal Lock https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock ) and something related to how the browser engine performs the transform.
Btw you hardly realize that with simple rotations especially if you do not animate them hence you have no idea of the intermediate states to reach the final orientation.
I like using raw CSS but for some complex cases ( parallax scroll + 3D animations websites ) you hardly can avoid using GSAP...